# There's an issue somewhere in my Python code.. I can't find where it's at

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know what's wrong with it.. I run it and I'm able to input a number but then it stops working. It says, "TypeError: play_game() missing 1 required positional argument: 'limit.' But I'm not sure what's missing there??

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import random

def display_title():
    print("Guess the number!")
    print()

def get_limit():
    limit = int(input("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: "))
    return limit

def play_game(limit):
    number = random.randint(1, limit)
    print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
    while True:
        guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        if guess < number:
            print("Too low.")
            count += 1
        elif guess >= number:
            print("Too high.")
            count += 1
        elif guess == number:
            print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
            return

def main():
    display_title()
    again = "y"
    while again.lower() == "y":
        limit = get_limit()
        play_game()
        again = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
        print()
    print("Bye!")

# if started as the main module, call the main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `play_game()` should be `play_game(limit)`, right?

Comment: @hts95 you are not passing `limit` argument while call  `play_game()` function, see in `main()` function.

Comment: play_game() method expect a value as you define def play_game(limit) , so in your main function call play_game() like : play_game(limit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, play_game() needs the parameter limit. I've done a quick check on your code, and there is some additional problem

- the count variable isn't initialized
- you calculate the random number in every step
- guess > number should be used instead of guess >= number

Here is the fixed code, it works for me. I hope it will be usefull:

```
import random

count = 0
number = -1

def display_title():
   print("Guess the number!")
   print()

def get_limit():
    limit = int(input("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: "))
    return limit

def play_game(limit):
    global number, count
    if number == -1:
        number = random.randint(1, limit)
        print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
    while True:
        guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        if guess < number:
            print("Too low.")
            count += 1
        elif guess > number:
            print("Too high.")
            count += 1
        elif guess == number:
            print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
            return


display_title()
again = "y"
while again.lower() == "y":
    limit = get_limit()
    play_game(limit)
    again = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
    print()
print("Bye!")
```

Comment: I dont understand why this answer is accepted while this code have same issue.did you run your code?

Comment: I did run it and it ran how it was supposed to.. I didn't get any errors or anything..

Answer (score 2):

You have defined your `play_game` function to take `limit` as a parameter, but when you call this function in your `main` loop, you don't supply a value in the brackets of `play_game()`.

You could either try adding that `limit` value that you've specified by calling it like

```
play_game(25)
```

Or, based on your code, since you're asking the user to provide a limit, call it like:

```
play_game(limit)
```

Or, if you want to be able to call `play_game()` without setting a limit, then change your play_game definition line to something like:

```
def play_game(limit=25):
```

Which will set a default value of 25 whenever that function is called without supplying the limit value.

Answer (score 0):

In your main you are calling `playgame()` without providing a limit as an argument.

Your main should look something like

```
def main():
    display_title()
    again = "y"
    while again.lower() == "y":
        limit = get_limit()
        play_game(10)
        again = input("Play again? (y/n): ")
        print()
    print("Bye!")
```